# How to get list of all transactions on all accunts in parity wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, json-rpc, rpc

I'm looking for simplest way how to get list of all transactions(incoming, outgoing, external, internal, confirmed, unconfirmed) on all accounts created in parity wallet. The listing should support pagination so it can work efficiently with 10 000+ account and 100 000+ transactions.

I prefer not to:

- use 3party apis (etherscan)
- write smart contract
- parse whole blockchain
- periodically observe accounts one by one

I would like to get transactions similar way bitcoind rpc works

I know there is no simple answer yet. I suppose parity's (or geth) job. If it's missing such functionality now, I'm ready to support developers financially.

Comment: it's not duplicate, i'm looking transactions for all accounts, not just one

Answer (score 0):

There's [no method for such a functionality for ETH](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1897) yet.

Ethereum's Classic `geth` implementation has the [`geth_getAddressTransactions()`](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/JSON-RPC#geth_getAddressTransactions) which [does precisely what you want](https://medium.com/@isaac_/geth-classic-v5-2-introducing-geth-getaddresstransactions-133c76fa82d1).

The options you have right now for ETH, are the ones you listed.